# pattern searching in perl

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(FILE1,"/cygdrive/c/cpros/karthik/molk.txt");

my $line = < FILE1 > ;
print $line ;
close(FILE1);
open(FILE2,"/cygdrive/c/cpros/karthik/folk.txt");
my $closet = < FILE2 >;
print $closet;
while($closet = < FILE2 >) {
    if($closet =~ /$line/) {
        break;
    }
}
```

But the code it not working. I want to search the pattern that is stored in $line in a file named folk.txt line by line but its not working whats wrong in my code?
sorry for my broken questions the first line of molk.txt contains a name jack and it should searched in folk.txt. sorry guys but i found where i made the mistake .

Comment: What does it do? Can you show us sample contents from molk.txt and folk.txt?  The first line from molk.txt, and the first 5 lines or so from folk.txt?

Comment: have you tried calling `chomp` to `$line` after reading?

Comment: guys i got it . Actually its the code I have been trying from a week and finally i did it. Its an interface between c and perl.I am so happy now i will create it as library and use it in c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`< FILE1 >` is not the same as `<FILE1>`. Yes, the perl lexer is whitespace-sensitive! (Actually, it is worse than that: it's probabilistic. But losing the spaces should be enough in this case.)

Comment: thats not the problem actually

Comment: cody: If that does not solve your problem, then please update your question to remove the spaces, and add the info I requested in my comment.

Comment: @Tim: Yes. Look at toke.c in the Perl source distribution some day; you'll be amazed. (Or horrified, if that's not your cup of tea.)

Comment: @Kilian: Could you point me some specific probabilistic behaviour? toke.c is very long.

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur, @Kilian Foth is referring to the use of heuristics. `<>` is either a call to `readline` (`<$x> is readline($x)`) or to `glob` (`< $x >` is `glob(" $x ")`). The curlies in `map { $_ => 1 } @a` form a map block, but the curlies in `map { 1 => 1 } @a` form a hash constructor (and thus a syntax error). There are many more.